# How can I response to 2 key presses as a single press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making something like "Staff member details system for customers" using HTML and CSS. I did it so far without problem.

**Primary task of the system:**

Customer reads the duty and name of staff member while animating upward the list.
If he/she finds the member, he presses relevant key from keyboard or clicks the number from numbers panel.

[System interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mamo4.png)

[Member details page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTmsY.jpg)

There is no problem if the customer "clicks" the button. But, If his choice is keyboard, the problem arises. Because, our staff has 20 members. Customer can press numbers from 1 to 9. I need to let customer press 10, 11, ... to access new page with details of that member.

I couldn't find any solution by googling. Please let me know the way to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If the user presses `1`, how do you know it's user #1, or user #17 who hasn't pressed `7` yet? A delay? Or would you require user #1 to enter `01`? And presumably you don't mean "single press", but "a sequence of keypresses" - if you require them to press the digits simultaneously, one of the problems is there's no way for #11 to log in. If you have staff of twenty, it might be easier to give them letters than numbers?

Comment: @NH Darshana Prasad Gunarathna you can track continuously pressed keys in particular amount of time lets say you want to type 20 you can track 2 and 0 key pressed after immediate one another with 5 seconds of time difference. And pressed key should be integer not string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to wait and check if there is going to be another key happened within some amount of time. It means that when the first key is pressed then you fire the function to wait and see if the user is going to press another key.

For example,
when the user press 1, you call setTimeout() and wait for 3 seconds. If within the 3 seconds, the user has not pressed another key then we assume that the user intended to input 3. However, if the user presses more then it will concatenate with the previous key(s). So, if the user pressed 7 within the 3 seconds then we will assume that the user intended to key in 17.

Also you can do this for more digits using the same method.

Comment: Inplace of using a setTimeout, a better solution would be to use the debounce method provided by lodash. You can read about it here: https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce